# Off-diagonal submatrices of a normal matrix have the same Frobenius norms

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

> Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$ where $A_{11} \in \mathbb{C}^{k \times k}$ and $A_{22} \in \mathbb{C}^{(n-k) \times(n-k)}$ for some $1 \leq k<n$.
> Prove that if $A$ is normal, then $\|A_{21}\|_{\text{F}} = \|A_{12}\|_{\text{F}}$.

---

I tried to use block matrix multiplication or Schur decomposition, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is normal we have $$A^h_{11}A_{11} + A^h_{21}A_{21} = AA^h_{(k\times k)} = A_{11}A^h_{11} + A_{12}A^h_{12} $$ where $AA^h_{(k\times k)}$ is the matrix $AA^h$ with rows and columns of index $>k$ set to $0$.

Thus $$\operatorname{Tr}(A^h_{11}A_{11}) + \operatorname{Tr}(A^h_{21}A_{21}) \\= \operatorname{Tr}(A^h_{11}A_{11} + A^h_{21}A_{21}) \\= \operatorname{Tr}(A_{11}A^h_{11} + A_{12}A^h_{12}) \\= \operatorname{Tr}(A_{11}A^h_{11}) + \operatorname{Tr}(A_{12}A^h_{12}) \\=\operatorname{Tr}(A^h_{11}A_{11}) + \operatorname{Tr}(A_{12}A^h_{12})$$
where the last equality holds since $\operatorname{Tr}(CD) = \operatorname{Tr}(DC)$ for any pair of matrices $C,D$.

Thus $$\operatorname{Tr}(A^h_{21}A_{21}) = \operatorname{Tr}(A_{12}A^h_{12})$$ which is equivalent to the thesis.

Comment: I might have made a mistake (so double check my proof), since my linear algebra skills are a little rusty.

Comment: I forgot to relate with trace(). Thanks!

Comment: Please consider using `\operatorname{Tr}`